# Why does javascript modify predefined shiny UI elements but not those added with insertUI?

Tags: javascript, css, r, shiny

I want to control attributes of a class of UI elements with JavaScript, but it only works for elements that existed when the app was initialized and not subsequent additions from `insertUI`.

In this example a new colored box is inserted with each press of the button. A `<script>` defined with the UI changes the color according to an input selection, but it only works for the initial div. Why does it not work for the additional divs?

```
library(shiny)
library(magrittr)

# Creates a div containing a div with text and a div with background color
insertBox = function(Id)
{
  boxDiv = tags$div(id = paste0("color_", Id),
                   style = "height:30px; width: 30px; background-color: blue;"
  )

  return(boxDiv)
}

# Script to change the value of an attribute for all divs whose id prefix matches Id
jsChangeDivAttr = function(event, Id, attribute)
{
  script = tags$script(HTML(paste0("$(document).on('shiny:inputchanged', function(event) {
    if(event.name == '", event, "') {
        document.querySelector('[id^=\"", Id, "\"]').style.setProperty('", attribute, "', event.value);
    }
  });")))
  
  return(script)
}

# UI
ui = fluidPage(
  # Scripts to change div properties
  tags$head(
    jsChangeDivAttr(event = "boxColor", Id = "color", attribute = "background-color")
  ),

  # Select color for color div
  selectizeInput("boxColor", choices = c("blue", "red"), label = "Box color"),

  # Button to insert new div
  actionButton("insertBoxButton", label = "Insert box"),

  # Insert text and color divs
  insertBox(0)
)

# Server
server = function(input, output, session)
{
  # Used to create divs with unique ids
  idCount = reactiveVal(0)
  
  # Insert boxes below the last one on page
  observe({
    # Id to insert this div after
    Id = idCount()

    # Id to give this div
    idCount(idCount() + 1)

    # Insert this div
    insertUI(selector = paste0("#color_", Id), where = "afterEnd", ui = insertBox(idCount()))
  }) %>% 
    bindEvent(input$insertBoxButton)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

##### Edit 2023-08-30

Made to work as intended in response to the information below from @Stéphane Laurent

```
script = tags$script(HTML(paste0("$(document).on('shiny:inputchanged', function(event) {
  if(event.name == '", event, "') {
    var divs = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=\"", Id, "\"]');
    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
      divs[i].style.setProperty('", attribute, "', event.value);
    }
  }
});")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you use `querySelector`. The `querySelector()` method returns the first element that matches a CSS selector. To return all matches (not only the first), use the `querySelectorAll()` instead.